# Create an Array from Keys in JSON Data

Tags: arrays, json

I need to create an array from a list of Keys in JSON data. The current data looks like this:

```
    {
"Investment": [
    {
        "name": "Average",
        "value": "170.0"
    }
],
"Recordkeeping Administration": [
    {
        "name": "Average",
        "value": "88.0"
    }
],
"Total Bundled": [
    {
        "name": "Average",
        "value": "268.0"
    }
],
"Trustee": [
    {
        "name": "Average",
        "value": "10.0"
    }
],
"chart_type": [
    {
        "name": "column",
        "value": "column"
    }
]
```

}
I need an array that looks like this: ["Investment", "Recordkeeping Administration", "Total Bundled", "Trustee"]

Comment: What programming language? I don't have my crystal ball with me at the moment ...

Comment: javascript: `Object.keys(o);`, php: `array_keys(o)`

Comment: Joshua K, you're a lifesaver! That was exactly what I needed. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joshua K. Object.keys(o) worked perfectly.

Comment: That's assuming you don't care what order the array is in. There's no guarantee it will always preserve the order, but it might.